# Memory leak, ChangeTracking JPA, Glassfish 3.1, Eclipselink 2.5

Tags: java, jpa, memory-leaks, eclipselink, glassfish-3

Just having a hard time finding a big memory leak in a java ee application running on a Glassfish 3.1.2 with Eclipselink 2.5.x

[image: MAT Memory Analysis]
We have lot's of more instances of the user entity in memory than we have users in the database. 
And the change tracking of the persistence functionality is going mad with 8 MB for each user. 
At the end it spends more than 2 GB for something that should be maybe 2 MB.

Does anybody have an idea how something like this can happen?

I tried to reproduce it in a small application but could not see a similar behavior.

Comment: This profile shows a UserCache class holding everything - what is in it and why?  How are you caching the user objects and for how long?

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer. My customer is trying to speed up access to some informations using google guave cache. One mistake is, I guess, to put @Entities into the cache. Somehow entitymanager and guave cache are holding those objects for ever in memory. But it should not be 2.5 GB. There is only 14000 users in total. I don't understand why change tracking is so huge. The data is never changed.

Comment: I don't think your change tracking instance itself holds that much memory; you didn't exactly  break out what the change tracker is holding onto.  It may have a link to the context though, and it is likely that context that holds the bulk of the memory.  The context will hold every entity that was read through it, which can quickly add up.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that they load the data via a singleton bean and store the data inside the singleton bean with a guave cache (like a hashmap). Would that cause what you say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting the parts of the DAO Service into pieces I found a way how to prevent this behaviour.

I spareated the guave cache from the JPA components and I used Pojo's inside the cache instead of detached entities. So I'm 100% sure that there is nothing is referencing to the cached data.

Answer (score 0):

If these are meant to be read-once type instances that the application caches statically, maybe change tracking on those instances is a bad idea, as all changes are tracked for their lifetime, building up until you release them.

See [this](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_changetracking.htm) for how to use deferred change tracking on a single entity